# Razor modal component with GUID as ID

Tags: .net, razor, blazor, modal-dialog, guid

Can someone explain why there is a bug here in certain situations?

I created modal as a razor component with GUID ID like you can see below. When I am trying to open the modal component by clicking a button as it is shown below, I am getting same error like is on the screenshot.

At first I thought error appears because Guid ID was generating wrong, but the modal ID and the button data-bs-target that invokes are the same. The error disappears when I set Modal ID to static or when there is a very large number of elements on the page which is generated.

Code from index page:

```
        <div class="row alignToEnd ">
        <button class="roundButton " data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#@modalPickerDevice.ID"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
    </div>
<ModalPickerDevice @ref="modalPickerDevice"/>

@code{
    protected ModalPickerDevice modalPickerDevice = new();
}
```

Razor component:

```
<div class="modal fade " id="@ID" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" tabindex="-1" style="overflow-x: auto;">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content ">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title"></h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close py-0" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
@code{
    public string ID { get; private set; } = $"ModalPickerDevice{Guid.NewGuid()}";
}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use Bootstrap modals in Blazor. Some of the JS stuff doesn't play well with the Blazor virtual DOM. Search "Blazor Modal Dialog" on Bing for plenty of implementations you can use.  You don't need to build your own.

Comment: Try this https://gist.github.com/conficient/ba98d1662c659e170ec16650acea05c8